# Simplify notation in math operations within dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

Say I have a dataframe `data` with 5 variables, `var1,var2,var3,var4,var5`. Imagine I want to do the following operation:

```
sqrt(data$var2)*(data$var4+data$var1)/data$var3 + data$var5/log(data$var3)
```

Is there a simpler way to just call the formula as follows?

```
sqrt(var2)*(var4+var1)/var3 + var5/log(var3)
```

Perhaps within another function? `apply` or the like? Can't get how to do it properly. Removing variables from the dataframe is not a desirable option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just wrap using `with`

```
with(data, sqrt(var2)*(var4+var1)/var3 + var5/log(var3))
```

---

Or another option is `transform`

```
transform(data, new = sqrt(var2)*(var4+var1)/var3 + var5/log(var3)))
```

---

Another option which is **undesirable** is creating column names as objects in the global env with `attach`. Then, can use the objects directly.  But, it is not recommended because this will pollute the env with lots of objects and can have some side effects

```
attach(data)
sqrt(var2)*(var4+var1)/var3 + var5/log(var3)
```

Comment: also `within()`

Comment: Follow up question. Simplification was for `data$...` What about if all variables are subsetted? For instance, `var_n[var3 > 3 && var2 < 10]` How not to pass the subset [[]] to each variable? Is there a way to simplify that too?

Comment: @luchonacho you can use `transform(subset(data, var3 > 3 & var2 < 10), new = sqrt(var2)*(var4+var1)/var3 + var5/log(var3)))`